# MySQL Query across multiple similar views

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting

I'm trying to write a query that compounds many MySQL Views. The MySQL version I'm using is the latest that Amazon's AWS RDS service provides. These views look like:

View 1: "Count of AAA Events"

- Col1: Timestamp
- Col2: Count

View 2: "Count of BBB Events"

- Col1: Timestamp
- Col2: Count

I have a about 100 of these views.

I would like to have a query that shapes this data to look like this:

- Col1: Timestamp
- Col2: Count
- Col3: Event Type

That means the data would look like:

```
2013-01-01T00:00:00Z    10     BBB
2013-01-01T00:00:00Z    10     AAA
2013-04-10T00:00:00Z    26     AAA
2013-04-10T00:05:00Z    28     AAA
```

The timestamps will NOT be unique, but the combination of Time + Event Type is unique.

I've tried a wide array of approaches, but nothing has given me quite what I want. Performance isn't an issue, as these are summary reports, not OLTP queries.

Any suggestions for a good way to approach this?

Comment: only mysql or php+mysql?

Comment: Just MySQL. I'm actually pulling the Query results into Excel as input to Pivot Tables.

Comment: ``SELECT TABLE_NAME, count(*) FROM information_schema.`TABLES` WHERE TABLE_TYPE LIKE 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'database_name' GROUP BY table_Name;``    Might get you started  (100% untested). Although you lose the timestamp with this, so that wouldn't work. I hope you don't need to UNION every view..

Comment: So, the approach is to run a dynamic query doing a `UNION` over all your views. Obviously this is done through a loop over  `information_schema.TABLES` or simply the result of `SHOW TABLES WHERE...;` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT Col1, Col2, "AAA" AS Col3 FROM View1

UNION ALL

SELECT Col1, Col2, "BBB" AS Col3 FROM View2

UNION ALL

SELECT Col1, Col2, "CCC" AS Col3 FROM View3

UNION ALL

.
.
.

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

With help from the folks above, the final results look like this:

```
Select * from 
(
  (SELECT PointInTime, (Col1+Col2+Col3) as Failures, "ApiName1" FROM Table1)
  union all 
  (SELECT PointInTime, (Col1+Col2+Col3) as Failures, "ApiName2" FROM Table2)
  order by PointInTime
) as X;
```

The use of the sub-query lets me shape the final column names should I need to.

That gives results that look like:

```
PointInTime    FailedBuckets     API
2013-01-01            0          ApiName1
2013-01-01            1          ApiName2
2013-01-02            0          ApiName1
2013-01-02            1          ApiName2
```